# What is the role of TATA box in transcriptional regulation?

Tags: gene-expression

I know what is the TATA box, but I wish to know whether it has specific roles in transcriptional regulation.

Comment: what have you searched? there's a lot out there - even on non-scientific sites like wikipedia...

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh, I have searched, but I've not found the specific role of TATA box in transcriptional regulation.

Answer (score 3):

TATA box serves as a binding site for the [TATA-binding protein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TATA-binding_protein) (TBP; and its associated factors, together comprising the [TFIID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_factor_II_D)).

TATA-box is one of the basic promoters present in many genes and therefore TBP is a general transcription factor i.e. TATA-box and TBP do not have specific roles. TATA-box is like a minimal promoter.

Answer (score 0):

`TATA box` simply is a type of promoter sequence, which specifies to Transcription Factors where transcription begins - which is usually 30bp downstream of `TATA Box`. Transcription factors can bind to the TATA box and recruit the `RNA polymerase` enzyme to synthesize RNA.

Comment: Specific transcription factors don't bind to TATA box. TBP does, and it is a general transcription factor.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thanks but I am sorry I didn't get you. Where is my answer stating about Specific TFs?

Comment: TATA box is bound by the TBP. You said "Transcription factors bind to TATA box", which may imply any transcription factor.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thanks! I got you now. What do you mean when you say "TBP is a general TF"?

Comment: See http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/44732/3340. Basically, it means that is required by a lot of genes to carry out transcription and it is constitutively expressed.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thanks man! Opened a new thing for me.

Answer (score 0):

From [Nature](http://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/tata-box-313):

> A TATA box is a DNA sequence that indicates where a genetic sequence
>   can be read and decoded. It is a type of promoter sequence, which
>   specifies to other molecules where transcription begins. [...]. The
>   TATA box is named for its conserved DNA sequence, which is most
>   commonly TATAAA. Many eukaryotic genes have a conserved TATA box
>   located 25-35 base pairs before the transcription start site of a
>   gene. The TATA box is able to define the direction of transcription
>   and also indicates the DNA strand to be read. Proteins called
>   transcription factors can bind to the TATA box and recruit an enzyme
>   called RNA polymerase, which synthesizes RNA from DNA.